# Android JSONObject Error

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am Registered then i'm trying to login but " Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject " this error is showing i don't know what to do kindly help me please.

This is my Java Code:

```
package com.example.kamran.ebloodbank;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnLogin;
    EditText userName;
    EditText password;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String logInUrl = "https://wwwkamranalitk.000webhostapp.com/donor_login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, logInUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if(success){


                                Intent intent = new Intent(LogIn.this, AfterLoginMain.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogIn.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("username", userName.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                        return parameters;
                    }
                };

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LogIn.this);
                queue.add(request);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1023450_admin", "admin", "id1023450_bloodbank");

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM blood WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $name, $bloodgroup, $contactnumber, $emailaddress, $area, $disease, $username, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
       $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["bloodgroup"] = $bloodgroup;
        $response["contactnumber"] = $contactnumber;
        $response["emailaddress"] = $emailaddress;
        $responce["area"] = $area;
        $response["disease"] = $disease;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and this is Logcat:

```
04-04 03:28:53.112 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.example.kamran.ebloodbank.LogIn$1$1.onResponse(LogIn.java:48)
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.example.kamran.ebloodbank.LogIn$1$1.onResponse(LogIn.java:43)
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
04-04 03:28:53.113 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-04 03:28:53.114 5357-5357/com.example.kamran.ebloodbank W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my JSON response:

{
  "success": true,
  "name": null,
  "bloodgroup": null,
  "contactnumber": null,
  "emailaddress": null,
  "disease": null,
  "username": "kamran",
  "password": "abc123"
}

Comment: I have generally seen this when the server encounters an error, or the request is malformed. It seems as if the issue is that you are receiving an HTML response, and attempting to parse it as JSON. Validate your request to the server by testing it in a browser.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: "Validate your request to the server by testing it in a browser." || Catch the exception and display an error?